# Azure DevOps Server: Why does Test Impact Analysis identify my tests both as "impacted" and as "not impacted"?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, xunit, impact-analysis, azure-devops-server

I have a .net framework (v4.8) class library project that contains 18 [xUnit.net](https://xunit.net/) unit tests that target another project.

In my [Azure DevOps Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/server/) (ADOS) [pipeline](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/) I have a rather standard Visual Studio Test task that find the test assembly with the unit tests and runs them.

When I enable the "Run only impacted tests" feature on the pipeline task, ADOS runs all of them on the first build, which is normal as this becomes the baseline build.

On the second build of the pipeline, things get weird. ADOS shows the build as having 36 unit tests, of which 18 are "not impacted" (and skipped = normal) and 18 were executed and "passed".

My question is - **Why are my unit tests executed when they've been recognized as "not impacted"? How can I fix this?**

---

PS - I'm attaching a screenshot and the task log below and I've noticed two interesting things:

1. Looks like the test selection phase, at the very start, happened twice.
2. This error message appears 18 times:

   > TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : ... to test run.

   Googling for it yields no useful information

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of build showing issue]

Visual Studio Test task log:

```
2019-07-31T13:25:33.3027955Z ##[section]Starting: Redacted tests

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3042189Z ==============================================================================

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3042843Z Task         : Visual Studio Test

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3043811Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3044138Z Version      : 2.143.8

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3044323Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3044558Z Help         : [More information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)

2019-07-31T13:25:33.3044783Z ==============================================================================

2019-07-31T13:25:35.5490506Z SystemVssConnection exists true

2019-07-31T13:25:35.5492434Z SystemVssConnection exists true

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6518950Z Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6519796Z ======================================================

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6520669Z Test selector : Test assemblies

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6521225Z Test filter criteria : null

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6521656Z Search folder : C:\_work\169\s

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6523219Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6888410Z Run in parallel : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6933473Z Run in isolation : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6934221Z Path to custom adapters : null

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6953986Z Other console options : null

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6954775Z Code coverage enabled : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.6958141Z Diagnostics enabled : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7006840Z SystemVssConnection exists true

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7068611Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7069443Z ========================================================

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7090912Z Test selector : Test assemblies

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7101985Z Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7102753Z Test filter criteria : null

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7114572Z Search folder : C:\_work\169\s

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7121444Z Run settings file : C:\_work\169\s

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7129106Z Run in parallel : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7135940Z Run in isolation : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7185224Z Path to custom adapters : null

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7186782Z Other console options : null

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7193511Z Code coverage enabled : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7195285Z Diagnostics enabled : false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7202436Z Rerun failed tests: false

2019-07-31T13:25:35.7213303Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest

2019-07-31T13:25:35.9796440Z ========================================================

2019-07-31T13:25:48.9123895Z ======================================================

2019-07-31T13:25:49.1259524Z [command]C:\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.143.8\TestSelector\TestSelector.exe PublishCodeChanges

2019-07-31T13:25:51.5460715Z Is pull request flow: False

2019-07-31T13:25:51.5461897Z

2019-07-31T13:25:51.5462363Z ***************************** Section 'Get Files that were changed' Starting *****************************

2019-07-31T13:25:51.5462753Z Baseline build: http://redacted/tfs/Redacted/390eb9aa-e420-4922-8ef4-bb12632dda52/_build/results?buildId=26442

2019-07-31T13:25:51.5463129Z Baseline build id = 26442

2019-07-31T13:25:51.5463438Z Total files changed = 0

2019-07-31T13:25:51.6444164Z ***************************** Section 'Get Files that were changed' Ended ********************************

2019-07-31T13:25:51.6445042Z

2019-07-31T13:26:04.3435720Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" C:\_work\169\s\Redacted\Redacted.Tests\bin\Release\Redacted.Tests.dll /ListFullyQualifiedTests /ListTestsTargetPath:C:\_work\_temp\b76cadd0-b396-11e9-84b4-7144b5b4b30f.txt "/TestAdapterPath:\"C:\_work\169\s\""

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4913814Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4915501Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4916535Z

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4917502Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5867523]   Discovering: Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4918503Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5867523]   Discovering: Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4919413Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7084444]   Discovered:  Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4920310Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7084444]   Discovered:  Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4921380Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4922173Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4923076Z

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4924003Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5867523]   Discovering: Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4924894Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5867523]   Discovering: Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4925884Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7084444]   Discovered:  Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4926792Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7084444]   Discovered:  Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4927362Z

2019-07-31T13:26:07.4973829Z [command]C:\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.143.8\TestSelector\TestSelector.exe GetImpactedtests

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4002997Z

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4004545Z ***************************** Section 'Get Impacted Tests' Starting *****************************

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4005365Z Following tests are impacted.

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4005940Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test1

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4006587Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test2

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4007287Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test3

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4007967Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test4

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4008425Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test5

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4008946Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test6

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4009492Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test7

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4010065Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test8

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4010533Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test9

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4011052Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test10

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4011524Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test11

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4013893Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test12

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4015028Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test13

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4015617Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test14

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4016093Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test15

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4016626Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test16

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4017177Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test17

2019-07-31T13:26:09.4017718Z Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test18

2019-07-31T13:26:09.5412388Z ***************************** Section 'Get Impacted Tests' Ended ********************************

2019-07-31T13:26:09.5413181Z

2019-07-31T13:26:36.7905770Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @C:\_work\_temp\adfd8492-b396-11e9-84b4-7144b5b4b30f.txt

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3869927Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3870828Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3871108Z

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3872406Z vstest.console.exe /Tests:"Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test1,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test2,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test3,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test4,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test5,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test6,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test7,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test8,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test9,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test10,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test11,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test12,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test13,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test14,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test15,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test16,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test17,Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test18"

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3874590Z "C:\_work\169\s\Redacted\Redacted.Tests\bin\Release\Redacted.Tests.dll"

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3874969Z /Settings:"C:\_work\_temp\b5e34eb0-b396-11e9-84b4-7144b5b4b30f.runsettings"

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3875446Z /logger:"trx"

2019-07-31T13:26:37.3875824Z /TestAdapterPath:"C:\_work\169\s"

2019-07-31T13:26:37.6710107Z Starting test discovery, please wait...

2019-07-31T13:26:39.6038466Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.4368142]   Discovering: Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:39.6040363Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.4368142]   Discovering: Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:39.7546522Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5937753]   Discovered:  Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:39.7547684Z [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5937753]   Discovered:  Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:43.7883423Z 3.1075

2019-07-31T13:26:50.1977477Z [xUnit.net 00:00:02.0480239]   Starting:    Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:53.3389390Z 718.1859

2019-07-31T13:26:53.5472252Z Passed   Test1

2019-07-31T13:26:53.5603376Z 56.5764

2019-07-31T13:26:53.6326306Z 54.9699

2019-07-31T13:26:53.7154878Z 64.2715

2019-07-31T13:26:53.8069205Z 73.892

2019-07-31T13:26:53.9014648Z 68.4937

2019-07-31T13:26:54.0023435Z 80.3846

2019-07-31T13:26:54.1314930Z 100.5241

2019-07-31T13:26:54.2364680Z 80.3842

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3291170Z 69.7939

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3428291Z Passed   Test2

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3429229Z Passed   Test3

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3429629Z Passed   Test4

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3431016Z Passed   Test5

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3431880Z Passed   Test6

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3433438Z Passed   Test7

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3434523Z Passed   Test8

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3435127Z Passed   Test9

2019-07-31T13:26:54.3435892Z Passed   Test10

2019-07-31T13:26:54.4130603Z 59.9983

2019-07-31T13:26:54.4911591Z 60.3922

2019-07-31T13:26:54.5695728Z 54.5636

2019-07-31T13:26:54.6410513Z 55.6404

2019-07-31T13:26:54.7216412Z 62.6562

2019-07-31T13:26:54.7934494Z 53.8405

2019-07-31T13:26:54.9052845Z 92.4184

2019-07-31T13:26:55.0215033Z 90.1679

2019-07-31T13:26:55.0358313Z [xUnit.net 00:00:06.9133992]   Finished:    Redacted.Tests

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6290009Z Passed   Test11

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6291164Z Passed   Test12

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6292127Z Passed   Test13

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6292638Z Passed   Test14

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6292965Z Passed   Test15

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6293222Z Passed   Test16

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6293491Z Passed   Test17

2019-07-31T13:26:55.6293753Z Passed   Test18

2019-07-31T13:26:55.7055753Z Results File: C:\_work\169\s\TestResults\mossadmin_SRVSP2013D23_2019-07-31_16_26_53.trx

2019-07-31T13:26:55.7098705Z

2019-07-31T13:26:55.7103676Z Total tests: 18. Passed: 18. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.

2019-07-31T13:26:55.7105019Z Test Run Successful.

2019-07-31T13:26:55.7126127Z Test execution time: 11.7080 Seconds

2019-07-31T13:26:55.8276786Z [command]C:\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.143.8\TestSelector\TestSelector.exe UpdateTestResults

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0886259Z

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0887559Z ***************************** Section 'Update test results' Starting *****************************

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0888142Z Test results remaining to be updated: 18

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0888434Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test1 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0889274Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test2 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0890060Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test3 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0890582Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test4 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0891197Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test5 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0891663Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test6 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0894448Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test7 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0895370Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test8 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0895890Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test9 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0896359Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test10 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0896879Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test11 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0897955Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test12 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0898632Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test13 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0899585Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test14 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0900632Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test15 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0901513Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test16 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0902139Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test17 to test run.
2019-07-31T13:26:59.0902833Z TcmTestResultPublisher.ConvertResults : No matching tcm test case result found for test case result given by agent to publisher. Adding test case : Redacted.Redacted.Tests.RedactedTests.Test18 to test run.

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0903437Z UnMatched Results found. Adding them to test run.

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0904228Z Publishing test results to test run '2490'.

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0905286Z TestResults To Publish 18, Test run id:2490

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0905702Z Test results publishing 18, remaining: 0. Test run id: 2490

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0906262Z Publishing test results to test run '2490'.

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0906568Z TestResults To Publish 18, Test run id:2490

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0907212Z Test results publishing 18, remaining: 0. Test run id: 2490

2019-07-31T13:26:59.0907563Z Total not impacted test: 18

2019-07-31T13:26:59.1801393Z ***************************** Section 'Update test results' Ended ********************************

2019-07-31T13:26:59.1802118Z

2019-07-31T13:26:59.2962424Z ##[section]Finishing: Redacted tests
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably were running data driven tests, TIA(Test Impact Analysis) does not support data driven tests yet. 
Please check https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/accelerated-continuous-testing-with-test-impact-analysis-part-1/ for currently supported scope.
If your tests are not data driven, Could you share some sample test code for more investigation?

Comment: Thanks but no. No data driven tests in that suite.